# RFComm- client while loop does not end when server is killed

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bluetooth

I am using RFComm socket. I have a client loop where it does read and write in a loop. When the server exits I guess , the client should also terminate. But client is not terminating. It is not printing "client loop exited". My code is as follows-

```
    void* clientLoop(void* arg)

{
    char* server_address = (char*)arg;
    printf("\nserver address in clientLoop = %s\n",server_address);
    struct sockaddr_rc addr = { 0 };
    int s, status;
    char gpsMessage[128];
    int flag = true;

    struct timeval tv;

    // allocate a socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    if(s<0) perror("socket error in client loop");
    // set the connection parameters (who to connect to)
    addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    str2ba( server_address, &addr.rc_bdaddr );

    tv.tv_sec = 30; // 30 seconds
    tv.tv_usec = 0; // microsecs, set to 0 (or ...)
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
    // connect to server
    status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    if(status<0) perror("socket status  error in client loop");

    // send a message
    if( status == 0 ) {
        while(flag)
        {
            sleep(10);
            printf("clientLoop did not exited\n");
            prepareMessageToSend(gpsMessage);
            status = write(s,gpsMessage , strlen(gpsMessage));
           if(status == 0) flag=false;
            status = read(s,gpsMessage, 128);
            if(strcmp(gpsMessage,"Ring"))
            {
                printf("RING\n");
                system("espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 \"I've just picked up a fault in the AE35 unit\"");
            }  
           if(status == 0) flag=false;
        }
    }

    if( status < 0 ) perror("uh oh");
    printf("clientLoop exited\n");
    close(s);
   //return s;
}
```

Comment: *client is not terminating. It is not printing "client loop exited"* is it still there or does it crash?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things it is missing the include statements for the needed header files.  Rather than making us guess as to which header files are included, please post them.

Comment: regarding: `if(s<0) perror("socket error in client loop");` and `if(status<0) perror("socket status  error in client loop");` after returning from `perror()` the thread should exit, probably by calling `pthread_exit()`.  That same call should be at the end of the thread function.

Comment: the posted code should be checking the returned value from: `setsockopt()` and if failed, call `perror()` and `pthread_exit()`

Comment: always check the returned status from `write()` and from `read()`.  Amongst other things, the status can tell the code if the client is no longer available.

Comment: regarding: `if(status<0) perror("socket status  error in client loop");`  this is meaningless.  Suggest using: `if(status<0) perror("connect failed" );`

Comment: the functions `read()` and `write()` can return a <0 value.  When that happens, need to call `perror() so the reason the system thinks the function failed will be output to `stderr`.

Comment: if the call to `write()` failed to transfer any bytes, then why continue (for instance by calling `read()`) this would be a good time to cleanup, call `close()` on the socket, and call `pthread_exit()`

Comment: the function: `read()` does not NUL terminate the input char array, so a call to `strcmp()` will not make a valid match with the data read.

Comment: if the call to `write()` returns 0, then the client has not been told anything to do, so (probably) will not be sending more info.  Therefore, calling `read()` when `write()` failed is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the socket a timeout

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 30; // 30 seconds
tv.tv_usec = 0; // microsecs, set to 0 (or ...)
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
```

if the read cannot be performed within that time, the timeout is triggered.

Also

```
 status = read(s,gpsMessage, 128);
 // check status first, or if there is no ambiguity, check only the 4 first chars
 if(strncmp(gpsMessage, "Ring", 4))
```

(in case the message could not be set correctly)

Comment: I changed the code as above, but problem is not solved

Comment: `flag` is set to false only if status is 0, status could also indicate an error, or a timeout...